# While query using hive metastore using apache drill getting error unknown host exception

Tags: apache-drill, hive-metastore

I have successfully connected Remote hive metastore with apache Drill. I am able to show databases of remote hdfs and also able to see the table structure from database. But while querying on the database it is giving error

```
Error: SYSTEM ERROR: UnknownHostException: remotename
```

Here is my configuration of apache hive

```
{
 "type": "hive",
 "enabled": true,
 "configProps": {
 "hive.metastore.uris": "thrift://myremoteIP:PortofThrift",
 "hive.metastore.warehouse.dir": "/tmp/drill_hive_wh",
 "fs.default.name": "hdfs://IP address of remote:port of hdfs from /",
 "hive.metastore.sasl.enabled": "false"
  }
}
```

here are the successful queries 
  jdbc:drill:zk=local> describe `data_mcsc_mcsc_bill_info`;

and result.

```
    COLUMN_NAME       |     DATA_TYPE      | IS_NULLABLE  |
+------------------------+--------------------+--------------+
| tran_dt                | CHARACTER VARYING  | YES          |
| tran_tm                | CHARACTER VARYING  | YES          |
| bill_id                | CHARACTER VARYING  | YES          |
| policy_number          | CHARACTER VARYING  | YES          |
| policy_start_date      | CHARACTER VARYING  | YES          |
| policy_end_date        | CHARACTER VARYING  | YES          |
```

Answer (score 1):

More details will be required to provide a complete answer to your question. I can provide some debugging tips here.

- Verify that the machines running your namenode and metastore are accessible from the machine you are running Drill on. You can use the telnet command to verify that a socket can be opened. If this fails you have a firewall / connectivity issue.
- Validate that Drill can talk to your HDFS cluster by putting a csv file on HDFS and adding a storage plugin configuration for your HDFS cluster to Drill. Validate that you can query the file from Drill. If this fails you may have not specified the correct port for your HDFS namenode or there may be some other HDFS related issue.

If these debugging tips are insufficient please subscribe to the Apache Drill dev and user lists. You can look at the information here on how to do this http://drill.apache.org/mailinglists/. You can then send your question to the user list, and the Drill team can provide more interactive help with your issue there. Also please include the following information if you send your question to the user list:

- Your version of Drill.
- Whether you are running a drill cluster or you are running a simple standalone node.
- The version of Hive.
- The Distribution of HDFS you are using (e.g. Big Top, Hortonworks, Cloudera).

Comment: I am using Apache Drill 1.6.16 , and Hive 2.3.2 for querying Hadoop HDFS where Apache Drill is installed in standalone mode in my system.